Is $\operatorname{rank}(A)\subseteq\operatorname{TC}(A)$?
This question came to me when I was thinking about rank and transitive closures. Let $A$ be a set of rank $\alpha$ and let $\operatorname{TC}(A)$ denote the transitive closure of $A$. Is it true then that $\alpha\subseteq\operatorname{TC}(A)$? I couldn’t think of a counterexample, so I tried to prove it by transfinite induction, but to no avail.
For the case of $\alpha=1$ (Edit: and $\alpha=2$), I was able to work out a proof using the axiom of foundation showing that if $\operatorname{rank}(A)\geq\alpha$ then $\alpha\subseteq\operatorname{TC}(A)$ (and this is trivial for $\alpha=0$) but I couldn’t manage to generalize the argument.

$A=\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ has rank $3$, but $3\not\subseteq \mathrm{TC}(A)$.
Note that every element of $\mathrm{TC}(A)$ has size at most $1$, so $2\notin \mathrm{TC}(A)$.
This is the smallest counterexample. It's easy to check by inspection that the claim is true for all four sets of rank $\leq 2$.

Oh silly me, not checking up to $\alpha=3$ before trying induction…
